# cron fails with php8

Tags: cron

wp 6 civi 5.51

cron stopped working when webhost forced upgrade to php8
It's a site I've inherited - they have extension cronplus installed. I'm not sure if it's this or maybe wp-cli?

don't have cpanel access where i could generate the cron error

command is */5 * * * * /usr/bin/php /www/xxxxxx/public/wp-cli.phar --user=xxxxx --url=https://xxxxx.org.au --path=/www/xxxxx/public/ civicrm api job.execute auth=0 > /dev/null 2>&1

read somewhere that maybe password now required - but have to say a bit out of my depth here

Answer (score 0):

Try running `wp-cli` as a test, just to see if it works (eg. run it without parameters). If it does not, you just found the problem, so try the latest version.

Or if you want to move away from using `wp-cli` for this, you can try some other options documented here: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/jobs/